# iOS badge not clearing when setting applicationIconBadgeNumber to zero

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I can't get the app's badge to be cleaned.
After the app is opened, it should set applicationIconBadgeNumber to zero, i tried doing this in applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    ...
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    ...
}
```

and in applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    ...
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    ...
}
```

I never used them both at the same time, and i also out of desperation tried some other places and nothing worked.
is there another way to clear the app's badge? or there is some other thing i should do?

EDIT: i tried to delete/reinstall the app, and the badge persisted

Comment: Perhaps you have issues with logic. Maybe you are setting it to 0 and some other logic thereafter is regenerating based on whatever conditions you’ve set. Maybe some more context would prove beneficial

Comment: i don't know if i get what you are saying, but i do not set the applicationIconBadgeNumber anywhere else, i just confirmed that

Comment: this code is running on main/UI thread?  If in background thread, try dispatch to main queue

Comment: i did dispatch to main now, but the problem continue

Comment: How do you know it is not being set to zero? If you set it to zero when you come to foreground, you cannot see the icon, as the app occupies the screen.

Comment: i just press home, and the app continues to have the badge, and since i do not set the badge anywhere else, it should not.

Comment: And what exactly does this have to do with push notifications?

Comment: the badge is set by my automatic push notification

Comment: What do you mean it should not? If you have outstanding notifications, yes it should.

Comment: can you clarify? what is outstanding notifications? and if i want to delete them for good until next push notification, how can i do it?

Comment: You need to manage the user notification center.